# How can I display an amount of units in my table with the same value?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, localhost

Hello I'm making a webapplication with markers. I would like to show in my navigation a kind of notification circle with a number in it with the amount of appointments are displayed on the map. In my database they have a value that is 0 for not done and 1 for done. This value is displayed in an image below under status. I would like to display the amount of appointments with value 0 in my div. I can't figure out how though..

[image]

This is the code in my main file (with the nav):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="navi current-page" href="main.php"><i class="ion-map icons"></i>Kaart<div class="rondje"><?php include'notifications.php'; ?></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="navi" href="overzicht.php"><i class="ion-ios-list icons"></i>Overzicht</a></li>
    <li><a class="navi" href="instructie.html"><i class="ion-help-circled icons"></i>Handleiding</a></li>
    <li><a class="navi" href="index.html" onclick="return confirm('Ben je zeker dat je wilt uitloggen?')"><i class="ion-log-out icons"></i>Log uit</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I thought it would be in php:

```
while ($markers = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo $markers['status'];
    echo "</p>";        
}
```

Comment: I think I almost found it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked for myself.

```
<?php
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM markers WHERE Status=0 AND DATE (dag) = CURDATE()";
$results = mysql_query($query);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<div class="rondje">';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```